# Jenkins pipeline: use parent job's params and add to them to call child job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have x2 declarative pipeline Jobs, both with many many params.
How can I take the params provided to the parent, and add to them, to pass to the child job?

I currently define them all individually, but this is prone to mistakes as there's a lot of them.

I also have figured out it's possible to obtain a list of params and pass them to the child job:

```
script{
    def myparams = currentBuild.rawBuild.getAction(ParametersAction).getParameters()
    build( job: 'childJobName', parameters: myparams)
}
```

What I haven't figured out is how to add to this list as it's unmodifiable. I'd need to make a copy and add to that, but I've not had any success doing this.

Comment: lets say parent job has 20 params and child job has 22, of which 20 are the same as the parent. So I need to add two params to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi you can use `paramsArray =  myparams.collect()` which gives you the Array which you can modify later i.e. add or remove the values in it